# How to compute homology groups of manifolds with dimension > 2

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

I've been following this course by professor N. J. Wildberger (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ap2c1dPyIVo&list=PL6763F57A61FE6FE8) in algebraic topology. Very nice, also very **very** basic, but it suits me because I'm a physicist (no formal training in topology at all) who is interested in learning alg topology for possible applications in data analysis.

Sadly, the course finished abruptly when he was going to discuss algebraic topology in 3 dimensional manifolds. I'm interested in continuing with that, to learn how to deal with topological objects when you lose the ability to "see" the object (for instance, computing homology groups). Do you know of lectures, resources... to learn that?

Thanks.

Comment: A first step is probably to understand how one can build a $3$-manifold with two homeomorphic surfaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then, I recommend reading about Heegaard splitting. I would advise taking a look at this [website](http://analysis-situs.math.cnrs.fr/), especially [this part](http://analysis-situs.math.cnrs.fr/-Topologie-des-varietes-de-dimension-3-.html) but it is written in French.

Comment: I don't know French, but thanks for the references.